# Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo JobScheduler

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I tried to create a simple `JobScheduler` job just to see how it works.
but I keep getting this exception on runtime, I can't figure it out as I followed the guides step by step.

This is my call:

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), TestService.class);

JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1,componentName).setPeriodic(300000)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY).build();

JobScheduler tm = (JobScheduler)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

tm.schedule(jobInfo);
```

`TestService` doesn't do anything other than extends `JobService`.

Comment: JobScheduler was added with API-Level 21. Are you running your app on at least an Android 5.0 device?

Comment: that introduced in API 21. what version is your android>

Comment: I'm using Android 6 (API 23)

Comment: And you device is alsow Android 6?

Comment: My device is Android 6 (API 23) the compile SDK is API 21

Comment: Did you declare service `TestService` in the manifest file?

Comment: yes:
<service
        android:name=".TestService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="true"/>

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to add the permission `android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE` into your AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<service android:name=".TestService"
     android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
     android:exported="true"/>
...
</application>
```

Comment: Yes good, this seems to be the cause of most of such errors. I had the same error and it was resolved just by setting the permission on the service like above.

Comment: Keep getting the same exception even after adding that in the `AndroidManifest`

Comment: android:exported="true" . Does this can also has effect ?

Comment: @petryk33 I'm facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Napolean Did you find the answer to your query?

Comment: @ChiragMittal No. not yet. But I have this exported attribute added now.

Comment: 3 years later... So does it help?

Answer (score 2):

Try clean project. It was my case.

Answer (score -1):

My issue was that my Service was defined as an static inner class. The issue resolved itself once I moved the service class into it's own Java file

Comment: No, you can have services as static inner classes too: `<service android:name=".MainActivity$TestService" ...`