# IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{JobIntentService}

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, illegalargumentexception, jobintentservice

SO answers regarding this issue has not helped me, I have declared all permissions and already have, accepted answers in my code.

`AppInfoJobService`(CustomJobIntentService) throws following error on Android OS 8+ devices and it happens rarely, not able to reproduce. 
We enqueueWork in `BaseActivity`'s `onCreate`.We mainly have one activity and fragments.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{<app package>AppInfoJobService}
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2009)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1951)
   at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.enqueue(IJobScheduler.java:211)
   at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.enqueue(JobSchedulerImpl.java:53)
   at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$JobWorkEnqueuer.enqueueWork(JobIntentService.java:342)
   at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService.enqueueWork(JobIntentService.java:522)
   at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService.enqueueWork(JobIntentService.java:500)
   at <application package>AppInfoJobService.startWork(AppInfoJobService.java:254)
   at <application package>MyApplication.onStartStopChanged(MusicApplication.java:694)
   at <application package>AppStateMonitor.notifyStartStop(AppStateMonitor.java:150)
   at <application package>AppStateMonitor.access$000(AppStateMonitor.java:14)
   at <application package>AppStateMonitor$CreateDestroyRunnable.run(AppStateMonitor.java:71)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6545)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue on LAVA devices running Oreo.. did you find anything?

Comment: No not able to find anything, so I moved my code from JobIntentService to a simple thread.

Comment: Do you think the problem is caused with the fact that we are trying to start a jobIntentService in the onCreate of a fragment?

Comment: We are starting JobIntentService when our first Activity is created, inside a handler with 300ms delay not in fragments onCreate.why it is a problem in onCreate?

Comment: No it's not a problem.. it shouldn't be.. I am just trying to debug and investigate why this is happening.. and in my case its only occurring on LAVA devices running android 8.. anyways, I made it a priority to solve so hopefully I will soon find the bottom of the problem.. having said that, after calling your job inside post delayed handler, are you still encountering this error?

Comment: Yes, error is still there.I think JobIntentService has some internal problem in OS 8+. we get lot of crashes related to JobIntentService for version 8, 8.1 in our Crashlytics report.You can refer this link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63622293

Comment: the link that you have sent me is different than the issue that we are trying to resolve here. I have resolved java.lang.SecurityException of JobIntentService by writing a SafeJobIntentService which extends JobIntentService and catches the exception. check out this link https://github.com/evernote/android-job/tree/master/library/src/main/java/android/support/v4/app for the code to overwrite JobIntentService. DO NOTE: you have to add the files under android.support.v4.app (package / directory)

Comment: have you mentioned your AppInfoJobService class in your Manifest?

Comment: @Nikhil yes it is already mentioned

Comment: @shalini Can you update the question with AppInfoJobService Java class. So  I could have a deep understanding of the issue.

Comment: @Nikhil AppInfoJobService is simple class. In its onHandleWork method I am firing some Analytics events.I dont think there is any problem in this, as it is crashing just when "enqueWork(...)" of JobIntentService is called.

Comment: @shalini Have a look at this 

https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/commit/8025425e7f18c2756a8bc91c1cca58cd5dab3875

Hope you may find something useful.

Comment: @Bassel Mourjan Got the same crash report from a Lava Z61 running Android 8.1.0.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35740474/6117565

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is finally resolved after switching to the new [Android WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics#java)

Comment: I was thinking of doing the same. Is WM tested solution, I hope it just not add another bug count.

Comment: to be honest I waited till it was a stable release and applied it to my active app with 10k+ active users... so far, 3 crashes affected 1 user only

Answer (score 8):

**Note:** Starting a separate thread as I do not have enough reputation to comment and want to help the author.

This actually is an issue with LAVA devices having Android Oreo and works absolutely fine with other devices.

I too observed this on LAVA Z60s & LAVA Z61.

*Addining related information from crashlytics*
[image]

Comment: That's correct, and I am unable to reproduce since I don't have access to a LAVA device, hopefully somebody could have an answer/fix to this issue.

Comment: @BasselMourjan I was able to replicate the same. Can you try something like [this](https://github.com/evernote/android-job/blob/master/library/src/main/java/android/support/v4/app/SafeJobIntentService.java)?

You can neglect this as of now by adding an 'IllegalArgumentException' along with 'SecurityException' there.

Comment: I will try it in the next release.. why not.. but I don't think that it's the solution since the main problem is "No such service"

Comment: @BasselMourjan it is definitely not the solution but you can avoid a crash just to improve user experience.

Comment: I already have this applied to avoid SecurityException on android 8.. cheers

Comment: We are also seeing this same issue on Z60 device. Where you able to find any solution?

Comment: @SaranSankaran sorry for the delayed response but we could not find any solution for the same and ended suppressing the exception at our end.

Comment: @VrajeshHirani I called one of our users suffering from this issue and his description for the crash was as follows: "After installing the app everything works perfectly, but on second launch it crashes and he would re-install it once again for it to work"

Comment: I am now trying to reach LAVA's software development team but so far without any luck

Comment: @BasselMourjan the behavior remains same after user re-installs?

Comment: @VrajeshHirani according to the LAVA user, it works normally the first time after installation, then fails on second launch.

Answer (score -1):

My case is I didn't create service in AndroidManifest.xml, so it didn't find that service. 
To do that, add following to that :

```
    ...
    /activity>
    <service
        android:name=".YOUR_FOLDER.YOUR_SERVICE_FILENAME"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="false" />
    <receiver
        android:name=".YOUR_FOLDER.YOUR_RECEIVER_FILENAME"></receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: down voted because this is a different issue that we are discussing

Answer (score -2):

You cannot start a service or intentService using method startService while the app is background or application is gets killed and trying to restart the service.

As far as I can understand the situation is (as you said happened rarely) somehow app is trying to restart the application while the app is not in the memory.

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't address the specific issue in the question.  Namely why is JobScheduler.schedule throwing an IllegalArgumentException in this case.